# How to show errors in angularjs resource?

Tags: angularjs, bootbox

I try to show a dialog error when the a web api fails. I am using bootbox for this purpose.

The code is:

```
OrderService.get(function(response) {
    $scope.newOrder = response;
}, function(error) {
    $bootbox.alert(error.statusText);
});
```

OrderService is a service:

```
app.factory('OrderService', [
   '$resource', function($resource) {
   return $resource('http://myweb/api/orders/neworder', {});
}]);
```

The first time that I open the web page, it works fine and the error message is displayed.
If I refresh the page, then the bootbox disable the entire screen and I cannot close the bootbox popup dialog.

If I replace   `$bootbox.alert(error.statusText);`  by  `alert(error.statusText);`, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some module to implement bootbox, 'cos `$bootbox` must injected
If not then, you can simple use without $:

```
OrderService.get(function(response) {
    $scope.newOrder = response;
}, function(error) {
    bootbox.alert(error.statusText);
});
```

from [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com/#usage) page:

> Once you’ve got your dependencies sorted, usage is fairly
>   straightforward and much like any other JavaScript library you’ve ever
>   used. The library creates a single global instance of a bootbox object